# difference between node-sass-middleware and node-sass

Tags: node-sass

This is the 3rd time asking this issue.

> what is the difference between npm node-sass-middleware and node-sass?

express generator uses node-sass-middleware with command

```
express --view=ejs --css=sass --git <folderName>
```

on the other hand, some use node-sass, not node-sass-middleware.

what is the difference between those two? and which one is better?

cannot find any information on google and stackoverflow.

hope to get some answer this time. appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that the node-sass-middleware package contains the node-sass package, and I think there is a way to configure the node-sass package to run as middleware, but I haven't figured out how to do this (it is the old way of doing what the node-sass-middleware package does). If you are trying to decide between the two, the consensus seems to be to use the node-sass-middleware package.

Corey